# How to add minutes to time in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I have written this code but it's showing parse exception on the "Date d = df.parse(arrivalTime1);" line. I'm trying to write this simple program. The user types a time like 8:30 in an EditText, they also type an integer like 5 in another EditText which is the minutes to be added to the time. Then, the program automatically prints out 8:30, 8:35, 8:40, 8:45, 8:50, 8:55, 9:00, 9:05, 9:10, 9:15.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button calcuBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcuBtn);

        calcuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText arrivalTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.arrivalTimeEditText);
                EditText newCustomerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newCustomerEditText);

                int arrivalTimeIncrement = Integer.parseInt(newCustomerEditText.getText().toString());

                String arrivalTime1 = arrivalTimeEditText.getText().toString();

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Date d = df.parse(arrivalTime1);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(d);
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, arrivalTimeIncrement);
                String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());


                Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startIntent.putExtra("com.debashis.multiserverqueue.SOMETHING", newTime);
                startActivity(startIntent);


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: it's HH:mm so you will have to type in 08:30 also, you are not validating for random inputs like 26:68 etc...

Comment: Yes, I know that but this program itself is not running so can you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: What error are u seeing in logcat? Please share the exception stack

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to add a try catch block.

Comment: Oh cool... U had a compile time error :)